# Cmake external Dependency configuration

Tags: cmake

I have a an SDK for a robotic device called (Falcon Haptic Device), and I am trying to to compile a very simple example provided by the company itself but I want to set the linking and dependency configuration using Cmake.

On my disk I have the flowing files

- SDK

  - include

    - dhdc.h
    - drdc.h
  - lib

    - dhdms.lib
    - dhdms64.lib
    - drdms.lib
    - drdms64.lib

And in a different directory I have  my project I call it "MMT"

- MMT

  - mmt.cpp
  - include

    - dhdc.h
    - drdc.h
  - CmakeLists.txt
  - build

and I have the following cmakelists

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)
project(MMT)
include_directories(include)
add_library(foo STATIC IMPORTED)
add_library(fop STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "C:/Program Files/Force     Dimension/sdk-3.5.1/lib/dhdms.lib")
set_property(TARGET fop PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "C:/Program Files/Force Dimension/sdk-3.5.1/lib/drdms.lib")
add_executable(myexe mmt.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myexe foo fop )
```

I succeeded in generating the .sln file and when I open it it doesn't have any compelling error ... however when I run it i am getting a run time error saying "the apllication was not able to start correctly 0xc000007b ".
given that code (mmt.cpp) works fine when I run the provided .sln file from the company on 32 and 64 platforms... so what am I missing in the Cmakelists.txt ?

Comment: Are you on windows or Linux?

Comment: I am using  WINDOWS 64

Comment: Have you run your executable through dependency walker to make sure you've copied all the required DLLs?

Comment: lets put is this way... I have a dhd.dll and dhd64.dll in the SDK directory and I don't know what to do with them... should I copy them to the project directory and if i copy them where should i paste them? ... 

I also tried the following

Comment: I also tried the following

    add_library(foo SHARED IMPORTED)

    
    set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "C:/Program Files/Force Dimension/sdk-3.5.1/lib/dhdms.lib")
    set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY IMPORTED_IMPLIB "C:/Program Files/Force Dimension/sdk-3.5.1/bin/dhd.dll")

 gave me  error 
"fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2F0"

Comment: it's (almost) always best to copy and paste all required dll's into the same directory as the executable. If it works, you can set your cmake to do it for you as a post-build step.

Comment: it is not possible to paste the dll file in the same directory as the executable because this directory is only generated after i open the .sln file and i press (debug).
and i even pasted them to the exe directory (but after pressing Debug button in VS ) and still doesn't work 
so there must be away to link the dll through cmake but i don't know the  syntax to do so.

Comment: There is, but you need to figure out what the problem is before you try to figure out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. it turned out the there was no problem with CmakeList.txt. 
the way to solve the problem is that before the generation stage Cmake asks you to chose a generator I was to choosing (visual studio 10 2010) instead this I must have used (visual studio 10 2010 WIN64). 
NOTE that you need to link against hdhms64.lib if you chose this option.